# How do I merge multiple xarray data variables and their coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (AND obs_dim_0: 36, NAND obs_dim_0: 37, NOR obs_dim_0: 36, OR obs_dim_0: 30, XNOR obs_dim_0: 34, XOR obs_dim_0: 34, chain: 4, draw: 500)
Coordinates:
  * chain           (chain) int64 0 1 2 3
  * draw            (draw) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 493 494 495 496 497 498 499
  * AND obs_dim_0   (AND obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
  * NAND obs_dim_0  (NAND obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 31 32 33 34 35 36
  * NOR obs_dim_0   (NOR obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
  * OR obs_dim_0    (OR obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
  * XNOR obs_dim_0  (XNOR obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 28 29 30 31 32 33
  * XOR obs_dim_0   (XOR obs_dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
Data variables:
    AND obs         (chain, draw, AND obs_dim_0) float64 3.802 5.118 ... 4.205
    NAND obs        (chain, draw, NAND obs_dim_0) float64 5.619 6.705 ... 6.633
    NOR obs         (chain, draw, NOR obs_dim_0) float64 4.515 6.268 ... 5.068
    OR obs          (chain, draw, OR obs_dim_0) float64 4.323 5.856 ... 6.111
    XNOR obs        (chain, draw, XNOR obs_dim_0) float64 3.441 5.183 ... 7.014
    XOR obs         (chain, draw, XOR obs_dim_0) float64 4.9 6.517 ... 5.65
Attributes:
    created_at:                 2019-10-20T20:12:11.936807
    inference_library:          pymc3
    inference_library_version:  3.7
```

I would like to turn this into a data set with a single data variable (call it `obs`), and with a new dimension, `gate` that takes values `['AND, 'NAND', 'NOR'. 'OR', 'XNOR', 'XOR']`.  I would *also* like the six different dimensions/coordinates (`AND obs_dim_0`, `NAND obs_dim_0`, etc.) to be flattened into a single `var_idx` dimension.  That way I could address values by using `ds.sel(gate='AND', obs_idx=n)`.

There's a lot of discussion about fusing data sets, and I get the sense that I should be able to partition this one and put it back together, using some kind of split-apply-group, but I just don't get it.  I have tried selecting the variables and then stacking, but then I get xarrays instead of data set.  I have tried renaming the dimensions to all be `obs_idx`, but then when I try to set the coordinates, I can't because the different dimensions have different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

`xarray.Dataset.to_array(dim = 'gate')` should work.

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem and how will this code solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the error message I see isn't helpful: `emoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (6, 4, 500, 36, 37, 36, 30, 34, 34) and data type float64`.  Given the six dimensions at the end, I don't think xarray is fusing the variables, as opposed to just trying to jam them together.  To reiterate, I'd like the resulting data set to have a single dimension for all six gates. The above looks like it is keeping 6 different dimensions.